# Why is only the menu and sidebar effected by the color theme of Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

When I load in a theme pack, only the menu and the sidebar are effected by it and the text editor is left in its default state.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkIfB.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main window is colored according to rules in the [color scheme](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html). Some themes come with matching color schemes, others don't. Sublime ships with a number of different color schemes that you can try using the **`Preferences → Select Color Scheme…`** menu option.